# Allowing user to register only if field information matches the one from database in Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to allow a student user to register in the system only if the student_ID matches the one from database. But I don't know how to do it right.

```
class StudentData(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    student_ID = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=14)
```

```
class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=True)
    surname = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=True)
    student_ID = forms.CharField(required=True, max_length=14, min_length=14)
```

```
student_data = StudentData.objects.all().values('student_ID')
if form2.is_valid():
            cd2 = form2.cleaned_data
            phone = cd2['phone']
            for data in student_data:
                if data == 'student_ID':
                    student_id = cd2['student_ID']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use form validation:

```
class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=True)
    surname = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=True)
    student_ID = forms.CharField(required=True, max_length=14, min_length=14)

    def clean_student_ID(self):
        id = self.cleaned_data['student_ID']
        try:
            StudentData.objects.get(student_ID=id)
        except:
            raise ValidationError("Wrong student ID!!")
        return id
```

Comment: One small issue. Indeed it allows account creation only if student IDs match, but otherwise, the form will say passwords do not match and nothing about the student ID error.

Comment: Recorrecting the above statement. The error apears. Now I do not know why password error pops up.

Comment: Well, we don't have any password fields here or ... so something else should be causing it. maybe you have another form, or ... . Check your code. try checking the terminal for status and if you could't find the problem, try printing every steps so you can find out where it all goes wrong. Good luck.